# Referencing Multiple URLs on a Timer

Tags: javascript, html, tableau-api

I have a basic HTML/JavaScript query that references a URL. Instead of referencing a single URL, I'd like to reference 3, and have them cycle through on a timer.

**For example:**

currently  I have `URL1 = Dashboard1`, and I would like there to be a `URL2 = Dashboard2`, and `URL3 = Dashboard3`.

Here is my script:

```
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://public.tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 






  function initializeViz() {

   var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");

        var url1 = "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/ERXCommissioningDashboard/Dashboard1";

     var options = {

         width: 2000,

         height: 1200,

         hideTabs: true,

         hideToolbar: false,

        onFirstInteractive: function () {

        workbook = viz.getWorkbook();

        activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();

        }


    };



    viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url1, options);

  }  

  $(initializeViz);



</script>



<script type="text/javascript"> 



  function RefreshViz(){  

    //alert("test");

    viz.refreshDataAsync();    



     }



  if (document.addEventListener) {

    window.addEventListener("load", RefreshViz, false);

    } else if (document.attachEvent) {

      window.attachEvent("onload", RefreshViz);

    } 



    setInterval(RefreshViz, 30000); 



</script>



<div id="tableauViz">  

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Thank you! edited my script, however when run it only plays the first URL of the three. Here is the edited script:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://public.tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 



var vizs = [];
    vizs.push(initializeViz('tableauViz1', "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/SCADA_SERVER_DASHBOARD/Dashboard1"));
    vizs.push(initializeViz('tableauViz2', "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/ERXTrendingTool/Dashboard1"));
    vizs.push(initializeViz('tableauViz3', "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/ERXTrendingTool/Dashboard1"));

    function initializeViz(div, url) {

         var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById(div);
         var options = {
         width: 2000,
         height: 1200,
         hideTabs: true,
         hideToolbar: false,
         onFirstInteractive: function () {
             workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
             activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();

         }
    };

    return {div: placeholderDiv, vis: new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options)};

}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var visible = 0; //0, 1 or 2 - maintains state
        function rotate() {
         visible++;
            if (visible+1 > vizs.length()) {
            visible = 0;
         }

        //hide all
     vizs.forEach(function(vis, index, array) {
        vis.placeholderDiv.style.display === 'none';
        });

     //show and update
     vizs[visible].placeholderDiv.style.display = 'block';
     vizs[visible].viz.refreshDataAsync();

    }
    setInterval(rotate, 15000);


</script>

    <div id="tableauViz1">  

    </div>

    <div id="tableauViz2" style="display:none;">  

    </div>

    <div id="tableauViz3" style="display:none;">  

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additional Edits:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://public.tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 



var vizs = [];
    vizs.push(initializeViz('tableauViz1', "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/SCADA_SERVER_DASHBOARD/Dashboard1"));
    vizs.push(initializeViz('tableauViz2', "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/ERXTrendingTool/Dashboard1"));
    vizs.push(initializeViz('tableauViz3', "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/ERXTrendingTool/Dashboard1"));

    function initializeViz(div, url) {

         var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById(div);
         var options = {
         width: 2000,
         height: 1200,
         hideTabs: true,
         hideToolbar: false,
         onFirstInteractive: function () {
             workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
             activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();

         }
    };

    return {div: placeholderDiv, viz: new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options)};

}


</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    var visible = 0; //0, 1 or 2 - maintains state
        function rotate() {
         visible++;
            if (visible+1 > vizs.length()) {
            visible = 0;
         }

        //hide all
     vizs.forEach(function(viz, index, array) {
        viz.placeholderDiv.style.display === 'none';
        });

     //show and update
     vizs[visible].placeholderDiv.style.display = 'block';
     vizs[visible].viz.refreshDataAsync();

    }
    setInterval(rotate, 15000);


</script>


<div id="tableauViz1">  
</div>
<div id="tableauViz2" style="display:none;">  
</div>
<div id="tableauViz3" style="display:none;">  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See above for most recent edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:
Since you want to cycle the content in the divs I would probably create three divs and show/hide them (since recreating a `tableauSoftware.Viz` might be more overhead):

```
<div id="tableauViz1">0</div>
<div id="tableauViz2" style="display:none;">1</div>
<div id="tableauViz3" style="display:none;">2</div>
```

Then you can update your initialize method to take a div name and return the object. This makes it possible to create a simple array that holds all your vis objects, then you can rotate through them to toggle visibility and update the one you want to show:

```
function initializeViz(div, url) {

    var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById(div);
    var options = {
        width: 2000,
        height: 1200,
        hideTabs: true,
        hideToolbar: false,
        onFirstInteractive: function () {
            workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
            activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();

        }
    };
    return {
        div: placeholderDiv,
        viz: {
            refreshDataAsync: function (div, divNo) {
                div.innerHTML = divNo + ' updated: ' + new Date();
            }
        }
    };
}

var vizs = [];
vizs.push(initializeViz('tableauViz1', "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/SCADA_SERVER_DASHBOARD/Dashboard1"));
vizs.push(initializeViz('tableauViz2', "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/ERXTrendingTool/Dashboard1"));
vizs.push(initializeViz('tableauViz3', "http://ccapptabdev01/t/Gas/views/ERXTrendingTool/Dashboard1"));


rotate = function() {
    this.value = 0;
    return function() {
        this.value++
        if (this.value >= vizs.length) {
            this.value = 0;
        }

        //hide all
        vizs.forEach(function (viz, index, array) {
            viz.div.style.display = 'none';
        });

        //show and update
        vizs[this.value].div.style.display = 'block';
        vizs[this.value].viz.refreshDataAsync(vizs[this.value].div, this.value);
    }
};
setInterval(rotate(), 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/39eo3to2/

Original: 
One option is to create multiple `new tableauSoftware.Viz` objects and pass them into your refresh method:

```
function refreshViz(myViz){  
   myViz.refreshDataAsync();    
}
```

Then you can refresh them based on whatever interval works for that `viz`:

```
setInterval(function () { refreshViz(viz); }, 30000);
setInterval(function () { refreshViz(viz1); }, 20000);
setInterval(function () { refreshViz(viz2); }, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I just tried this set of code and, while it does play the first Viz, it does not cycle into the second Viz. The intent of this code is to have it cycle through all three Viz's and return to the first Viz, starting the loop over again.

Comment: Ah, and they should share the same div?

Comment: Yes, sharing the same div.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code, edited above, is static. The first URL is launched, but never refreshes on the 30 second intervals. Any additional help would be appreciated!

Comment: I had a typo (viz was called vis) on this line: `return {div: placeholderDiv, vis: new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options)};` you should be seeing an exception that `vizs[visible].viz` is undefined or something like that. Change to  `return {div: placeholderDiv, viz: new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options)};` and check for other vis. Note that the rotating of the divs and updating of the vizs are both happening every 15 seconds.

Comment: I've added in the edits, which included changes to the line `return {div: placeholderDiv, viz: new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options)};`. Additionally, I found two items in the loop having Vis instead of Viz, `workbook = vis.getWorkbook()` and `vis.placeholderDiv.style.display === 'none';`. However, I get the same issue when I run the script, namely, the first URL loads, but the dashboard does not start looping into the next URL. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: There were lots of problems actually running the sample code I posted, so I created a fiddle for you with a skeleton working example: https://jsfiddle.net/39eo3to2/

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help in this process. I'm migrating over to fiddle to try and work through the issue. I'm still not sure what's the problem, the url only seems to run when I include `return {div: placeholderDiv, viz: new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options)};` but will not loop. I'll be over on fiddle working through the issue. Again, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: The fiddle link allows you to update with your changes, then you can post that back here and I can help you debug further. Seeing specific errors would really help me help you :)

Comment: It looks like the web page isn't initializing. When I look at your script, it makes sense, however shouldn't there be a reference to `new tableauSoftware.viz`?  I feel like this should work:https://jsfiddle.net/Calbruin/2j9jfjn9/, however I'm getting no traction....

Comment: I don't know what that library is - so I didnt include it in my example - you'd have to add that JS file to the page either in the HTML section or the External Resources section to the left.

Comment: Ok, here's what I came up with: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/Calbruin/L37911p0/21/)

Comment: I now have two initialize functions each with their own URL. If you let the code run, you'll see that the RefreshViz runs the first Initialize function on Div1, and switches to Div2 after 30 seconds. I'm not entirely sure why the RefreshViz doesn't loop after 60 seconds, but if it did run again, I would basically  have a working model.

Comment: Additionally, here are the changes that I made to your Fiddle: [ https://jsfiddle.net/Calbruin/39eo3to2/44/ ]

Comment: not sure what your library is doing, but the general idea can be seen with this update: https://jsfiddle.net/39eo3to2/45/